# use functions in another package without attaching to the search path?

Tags: r, package

I use
`pkgs::function` notation to access a function in another package. This sometimes cause a problem like this one from `survival` package:

```
data(logan,package="survival")
resp <- levels(logan$occupation)
n <- nrow(logan)
indx <- rep(1:n, length(resp))
logan2 <- data.frame(logan[indx,],
                     id = indx,
                     tocc = factor(rep(resp, each=n)))
logan2$case <- (logan2$occupation == logan2$tocc)
survival::clogit(case ~ tocc + tocc:education + survival::strata(id), logan2)
```

it gives error:
`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "coxph"`

`coxph` is another function called internally from clogit function. Can this situation be avoided? I don't want to attach the package to the search path i.e. using `library(survival)` as per Hadley's `advanced r` best practices.

Comment: Why don't you want to attach the package?  You are using multiple functions from the package and it's obviously causing problems.

Comment: The package author built the call to `survival::coxph` piece by piece for the function. It'll be difficult to specify the package from the outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Amplifying @RichScriven's comment above.)

I'm not entirely sure where in *Advanced R* you're getting "don't use `library()`" as a best practice. Maybe in the [Functions section](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/blob/aa86007a5e3a87f552156bcf04c8fdf6d684b7d2/Functions.rmd) (please edit your question to clarify if I have the wrong bit!) where it says:

> The functions that are the easiest to understand and reason about are pure functions: functions that always map the same input to the same output and have no other impact on the workspace. In other words, pure functions have no side effects: they don't affect the state of the world in any way apart from the value they return.
>
> ... [points out that `library()` is an impure function because it changes the search path] ...
>
> It's generally a good idea to minimise the use of side effects, and where possible, to minimise the footprint of side effects by separating pure from impure functions.

Note the loose wording here: "It's generally a good idea to minimise ... where possible, to minimise ..." This doesn't mean "don't ever use `library()`" ...
It makes sense that you wouldn't want to put `library()` *inside a function*, or inside a package. If you're using a package, you can (should?) use `@importFrom survival clogit coxph` instead ... I find that putting the `@importFrom` tags at the beginning of each of my functions works well enough to tag the external functions being used therein that I don't necessarily need `::` to identify foreign functions (your mileage may vary).

However, if you're actually **writing code to do a survival analysis** then <s>bending over backwards</s>going to great lengths to avoid `library(survival)` seems unnecessary.

Amplifying @PierreLafortune's comment above: `clogit` internally contains the code `coxcall[[1]] <- as.name("coxph")`.  Your code would probably work as is if this line were changed to `coxcall[[1]] <- as.name("survival::coxph")`. You could post an [issue request on Github about this](https://github.com/therneau/survival/issues) if you felt strongly enough ...

Comment: I am using survival code inside a function in one of my packages. And yes, as per your citation and also the `devtools::use_package("survival",type = "Imports")` indication, using `::` notation is preferred in these scenarios. it also make it easier to find all the calls to a specific package. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do `survival::coxph->coxph`. Here you're just creating a new function in the environment with the same name so `clogit` should find the new function.

Comment: this works but it's not what I was after. thanks anyway